# Expected value of PMF

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expectation

I am stuck on this question, would appreciate any hints for how to start:

Let X have PMF
$$P(X = k) = \frac{cp^k}{k} for\:k = 1,2,...,$$
where p is a parameter with 0 < p < 1 and c is a normalizing constant.

*We have c = −1/ log(1 − p), as seen from the Taylor series:

$$−log(1−p)=p + \frac{p^2}{2} + \frac{p^3}{3} +....$$

This distribution is called the Logarithmic distribution. Find the mean and variance of X.

Now, this might be silly - but I'm a little confused by the statement 
"as seen from the Taylor series". However, I proceeded as such:

$$E(X) = cp + \frac{cp^2}{2} + \frac{cp^3}{3} + \frac{cp^4}{4} + ... $$

If we factor out *c* and *p*, we get:

$$E(X) = cp \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (1+\frac{p^{k-1}}{k}) $$

Does anyone have tips for proceeding?

**Update**
I computed E(X) as such:

$$E(X) = \frac{-1}{log(1-p)}\frac{p}{1-p}$$

Now I'm having trouble with finding Var(X), namely the first component, E(X^2). Here are the steps I've done:

$$E(X^2) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2P(X=k) =  \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2\; \cdot c \; \cdot\frac{p^k}{k} = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kcp^k $$

$$cp\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}kp^{k-1} = \frac{1}{1-p}$$

$$cp\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2p^{k-2} = \frac{1}{(1-p)^2}$$

$$E(X^2) = c\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}k^2p^{k} = \frac{p}{(1-p)^2}$$

Therefore our entire expression is:

$$E(X^2) = \frac{-1}{log(1-p)}\frac{p}{(1-p)^2}$$

Is this the correct expression for E(X^2)? Thanks so much.

Comment: you're close on the expectation, just factor out the c (not cp) and match term by term to the taylor expansion you just typed

Comment: Thank you, I'm not entirely sure what "match term by term to the taylor expansion" means. Do you mean my expression essentially becomes two Taylor series?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Already you have some confusion on the definition of expected value. You write
$$"E(X)=cp+cp^2/2+\dotsc+cp^k/k"$$
First, was it a typo to leave off the rest of the **infinite** sum? Second, you aren't even abiding by the definition of expectation. We know $P(X=k)=cp^k/k$ for $k=1,2,\dotsc$. So, by **definition**, 
$$E(X)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty kP(X=k)=c\sum_{k=1}^\infty k \cdot \frac{p^k}{k}=c\sum_{k=1}^\infty p^k$$
$$=c(p+p^2+p^3+\dotsc)=cp(1+p+p^2+\dotsc),$$
and if you recognize the final series and are aware of its closed form expression then you can easily conclude. If not, then you need to review geometric series.

The other answer shows you how to find $c$ so I have omitted that part. Finding the variance amounts to computing 
$$E(X^2)=c \sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^k$$ and using the fact that the variance is equal to $E(X^2)-E(X)^2$. To compute the new series, pull out a $p$ and recognize it as the derivative of the series $p+p^2+\cdots$. Is this doable?

Comment if you need clarification.

Comment: Thanks so much. I solved E(X). I updated my answer, as I'm a bit stuck on deriving E(X^2). Can you tell me if the method I used is correct? Thank you.

Comment: There is a mistake in the third displayed equation under your "Update" section. You wrote $cp \sum_{k=1}^\infty kp^{k-1}=1/(1-p)$, which is false on two accounts. First this is the wrong summation formula: we know $(1+p+p^2+...)=1/(1-p)$, which is not the series you need to evaluate for the second moment, but it is related. Second, you left off the constant $c$ on the RHS. What you must evaluate is $c(p+2p^2+...)=cp(1+2p+3p^2+...)$. This last series is the derivative of $(1+p+p^2+...)$ but we have a closed form of this already! I sincerely suggest you review geometric series.

Comment: Thank you so much, I am very behind on my calculus. Much work needs to be done!

Comment: @Workhorse you are very welcome and thanks for the upvote and acceptance. Everybody is always in need review of something :) and while there are things new and unique to probability that you will have to digest on their own, the meat of computations are typically based in the theory of series or integration. So, probabilistic life will be easier once these topics are second nature. Easier said than done, of course. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Recall that for a pmf we need
$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty P(X=k) =1$$
Plugging the pmf we get
$$cp+\frac{cp^2}2+\frac{cp^3}3+\cdots=1$$
$$\implies c\left[p+\frac{p^2}2+\frac{p^3}3+\cdots\right]=1$$
Now we need the logarithmic that you mentioned to conclude that
$$c[-\log (1-p)]=1\implies c=-\frac1{\log (1-p)}$$
Note that we are using properties of pmf not expectation.

Comment: Thank you, I am a little confused as to whether you just showed c equals this Taylor series, or whether you derived the expected value of this PMF? Or can I infer from your solution that the expected value IS the Taylor series, as denoted by c?

Comment: I just derived the value of c using properties of pmf and taylor series formula for $-\log(1-p)$.

Comment: However, to derive the mean (expectation) and variance you need to compute the sum of other kind of well known series. I haven't shown them here because your main concern was about $c$.

Comment: Sorry I didn't make that clear enough! I updated my question. Would a power series sum be moving in the right direction?